# scheduling crawling using scrapy with crontab

Tags: bash, scrapy, web-crawler, cron

i am newbie on using crontab, i just try to read article how to automatically scheduling crawling using scrapy every 5 minutes, and some article suggest to using crontab...
but i dunno how to implements the right script...

here my .sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/kautsar/Downloads/thehack
scrapy crawl thehack
```

i already +x to file runScrapy.sh

but when i try to using

```
crontab -e
*/5**** cd /home/kautsar && sh runScrapy.sh
```

then when i presses enter button the result is "?"
anybody know what it means? can you explain on this?
please show me the right way to do web crawling periodically which time is set by me.. thanks alot

Comment: Make sure you have spaces between the stars `*/5 * * * *`

Comment: stil same, i try "*/5 * * * * cd /home/kautsar && sh runScrapy.sh"
the result is "?"

Comment: Why not just use the full filename path `/home/kautsar/runScrapy.sh`

Comment: `i presses enter button` dont press enter button, just `:wq`  exit crontab console and reload cron service.

Comment: What is your EDITOR environment variable set to?  There is not a lot of information in that error message--but a naked `?` looks like what the bare-bare-bones  `ed` editor gives when it can't understand its input.  If that is the case, then a `wq` command might do the trick.  But you would be much better off executing an `export EDITOR=vim` or something similar.

Comment: @xxfelixxx stil same mate it cant...

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan i presses enter button to running crontab not for exit from crontab

Comment: @GregTarsa sorry mate i just newbie about this, can you explain more?

Comment: btw when i made crontab, i cant login as a root user?
or i can login as a root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your default editor is being set to `ed`. No idea why. If this is the case, you can read up on how to use in with the `man ed` command, but it would likely be better to configure the system to use your favorite editor.  Let's assume that is `vim`.  If it is not, replace `vim` with the appropriate name.

```
export EDITOR=vim
crontab -e
```

At this point, you should be in your favorite editor editing the `crontab` file.  I recommend you add a comment to the file similar to the one below.  I always do this to remind myself what all the columns are for the various asterisks.  `DoM` is Day of Month (1-31), `DoW` is Day of Week (0-7 or Sun/Mon/Tue, etc.). Then your shell script as a fully qualified file name (so you need not have the `cd` and the script invocation).

```
# min hr DoM mon DoW cmd
  */5 *  *   *   *    sh /home/kautsar/runScrapy.sh
```

At this point, you should be able to save and exit as you would using your editor.

There are other pitfalls awaiting you in a `crontab` file.  Read `man 5 crontab` and pay particular attention to the definitions of PATH and HOME.  `cron` runs in abbreviated environment, not your login environment, so sometimes the PATH variable needs to be set.  You may find it useful that $HOME is set to your home directory.  For instance, your command could be `$HOME/runScrapy.sh`.  Finally, you can set MAILTO to be the address to which `cron` sends any command output, which can be useful if outgoing email is not configured on your system.